# What is the difference between PTC and PORTC?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, pins, port

I am working on s32k144 controller in which I learnt how to configure pins as INPUT, while referring  data sheet I got to know the base address **GPIOC base address: 400F_F080h** which is matching with the PTC,
but the next line of PTC there is PORTC.

From the code I got to know that PTC base address is 400F_F080h which is GPIOC base address represented in the data sheet but the base address of **PORTC is 4004B000h** which is not in the data sheet.

so my question is what is **PTC,PORTC?** wats the difference?
why data direction is set by the using PTC base address and PORTC for setting as GPIO?

````
/* GPIO - Peripheral instance base addresses */
/** Peripheral PTA base address */
#define PTA_BASE                                 (0x400FF000u)
/** Peripheral PTA base pointer */
#define PTA                                      ((GPIO_Type *)PTA_BASE)
/** Peripheral PTB base address */
#define PTB_BASE                                 (0x400FF040u)
/** Peripheral PTB base pointer */
#define PTB                                      ((GPIO_Type *)PTB_BASE)
/** Peripheral PTC base address */
#define PTC_BASE                                 (0x400FF080u)
/** Peripheral PTC base pointer */
#define PTC                                      ((GPIO_Type *)PTC_BASE)
/** Peripheral PTD base address */
#define PTD_BASE                                 (0x400FF0C0u)
/** Peripheral PTD base pointer */
#define PTD                                      ((GPIO_Type *)PTD_BASE)
/** Peripheral PTE base address */
#define PTE_BASE                                 (0x400FF100u)
/** Peripheral PTE base pointer */
#define PTE                                      ((GPIO_Type *)PTE_BASE)
/** Array initializer of GPIO peripheral base addresses */
#define GPIO_BASE_ADDRS                          { PTA_BASE, PTB_BASE, PTC_BASE, PTD_BASE, PTE_BASE }
/** Array initializer of GPIO peripheral base pointers */
#define GPIO_BASE_PTRS                           { PTA, PTB, PTC, PTD, PTE }





* PORT - Peripheral instance base addresses */
/** Peripheral PORTA base address */
#define PORTA_BASE                               (0x40049000u)
/** Peripheral PORTA base pointer */
#define PORTA                                    ((PORT_Type *)PORTA_BASE)
/** Peripheral PORTB base address */
#define PORTB_BASE                               (0x4004A000u)
/** Peripheral PORTB base pointer */
#define PORTB                                    ((PORT_Type *)PORTB_BASE)
/** Peripheral PORTC base address */
#define PORTC_BASE                               (0x4004B000u)
/** Peripheral PORTC base pointer */
#define PORTC                                    ((PORT_Type *)PORTC_BASE)
/** Peripheral PORTD base address */
#define PORTD_BASE                               (0x4004C000u)
/** Peripheral PORTD base pointer */
#define PORTD                                    ((PORT_Type *)PORTD_BASE)
/** Peripheral PORTE base address */
#define PORTE_BASE                               (0x4004D000u)
/** Peripheral PORTE base pointer */
#define PORTE                                    ((PORT_Type *)PORTE_BASE)
/** Array initializer of PORT peripheral base addresses */
#define PORT_BASE_ADDRS                          { PORTA_BASE, PORTB_BASE, PORTC_BASE, PORTD_BASE, PORTE_BASE }
/** Array initializer of PORT peripheral base pointers */
#define PORT_BASE_PTRS                           { PORTA, PORTB, PORTC, PORTD, PORTE }
 /** Number of interrupt vector arrays for the PORT module. */
#define PORT_IRQS_ARR_COUNT                      (1u)
 /** Number of interrupt channels for the PORT module. */
#define PORT_IRQS_CH_COUNT                       (1u)
/** Interrupt vectors for the PORT peripheral type */
#define PORT_IRQS                                { PORTA_IRQn, PORTB_IRQn, PORTC_IRQn, PORTD_IRQn, PORTE_IRQn }

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(void) {

}
 int counter = 0;
 WDOG_disable();
 /* Enable clocks to peripherals (PORT modules) */
 PCC-> PCCn[PCC_PORTC_INDEX] = PCC_PCCn_CGC_MASK; /* Enable clock to PORT C */
 PCC-> PCCn[PCC_PORTD_INDEX] = PCC_PCCn_CGC_MASK; /* Enable clock to PORT D */
 /* Configure port C12 as GPIO input (BTN 0 [SW2] on EVB) */
 PTC->PDDR &= ~(1<<PTC12); /* Port C12: Data Direction= input (default) */
 PORTC->PCR[12] = 0x00000110; /* Port C12: MUX = GPIO, input filter enabled */
 /* Configure port D0 as GPIO output (LED on EVB) */
 PTD->PDDR |= 1<<PTD0; /* Port D0: Data Direction= output */
 PORTD->PCR[0] = 0x00000100; /* Port D0: MUX = GPIO */
 for(;;) {
 if (PTC->PDIR & (1<<PTC12)) { /* If Pad Data Input = 1 (BTN0 [SW2] pushed) */
 PTD-> PCOR |= 1<<PTD0; /* Clear Output on port D0 (LED on) */
 }
 else { /* If BTN0 was not pushed */
 PTD-> PSOR |= 1<<PTD0; /* Set Output on port D0 (LED off) */
 }
 counter++;
}

```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll find that these two symbols:

1. PTC
2. PORTC

Are identical.  It really depends on the difference between GPIO_Type and PORT_Type but if you look where those are defined, they are likely both just aliases for an address.

The convention for this is if you are using the register as a PORT, use the PORT_Type declaration.  If you are using one of the alternate functions on the pin/port, use the more general GPIO_Type.

But for all practical purposes, these two are interchangeable.  Whatever you do the best thing is to be consistent.

Comment: Which leaves open the question of why they are mapped to completely different addresses. (Perhaps the OP has cobbled together these #defines from two different header files for two entirely different MCUs?)

Comment: If they are likely both just aliases for an address, then why two different address?